# How to make a SQL query to display two columns values to one column?

Tags: c#, sql

I have a table structure like that as shown below. I want to show names under parent of names (where parent is ledger group)

[image: I expected result like this example]

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Sorry to say that we are not providing code writing services

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @t1 TABLE
(
 ParentGroup varchar(20),
 LedgerName varchar(20),
 TotalDebit float,
 credit float
)

INSERT INTO @t1
SELECT *
  FROM Table1

INSERT INTO @t1
SELECT Distinct ParentGroup, ParentGroup, NULL, NULL
  FROM Table1

Select LedgerName, TotalDebit, credit from @t1
group by LedgerName, TotalDebit, credit
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN TotalDebit IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE TotalDebit END)
```